# Making Checkers in python with the module pygame but are running into some logic errors I don't want the code changed just this problem fixed

Tags: python

The get mouse and place functions gets the pos of the mouse when its clicked down and realised, through a drag mechanism. The get valid moves finds all the valid moves for now its only the two diagonals when its a empty space. Maybe the way I unpack the tuple is wrong but when the if statement after the for loop is placed no movement happens. Can I get help but not change of the whole code. This is a only valid moves for the second player( the red pieces)

```
    def get_mouse_pos_and_place(self, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, number):
        end_column = int(end_x // SQUARESIZE)
        end_row = int(end_y // SQUARESIZE)
        start_column = int(start_x // SQUARESIZE)
        start_row = int(start_y // SQUARESIZE)
        if (self.board[start_row][start_column]) in (1, 2):
            if np.all(self.board[start_row][start_column] == 1):
                for x, y in self.white_valid_moves:
                    print(self.white_valid_moves)
                    if (x == start_column - end_column) and (y == start_row - end_row):
                        self.board[start_row][start_column] = 0
                        self.board[end_row][end_column] = number
            elif np.all(self.board[start_row][start_column] == 2):
                for x, y in self.red_valid_moves:
                    print(self.red_valid_moves)
                    if (x == start_column - end_column) and (y == start_row - end_row):
                        self.board[start_row][start_column] = 0
                        self.board[end_row][end_column] = number

    def get_valid_moves(self, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y):
        end_column = int(end_x // SQUARESIZE)
        end_row = int(end_y // SQUARESIZE)
        start_column = int(start_x // SQUARESIZE)
        start_row = int(start_y // SQUARESIZE)
        # For one
        if self.board[start_row][start_column] == 1:
            self.white_valid_moves.clear()
            if self.board[start_row + 1][start_column + 1] == 2:
                self.white_valid_moves.append((2, 2))
                self.board[start_row - 1][start_column + 1] = 0

            elif self.board[start_row - 1][start_column + 1] == 2:
                self.white_valid_moves.append((-2, 2))
                self.board[start_row - 1][start_column + 1] = 0

            elif self.board[start_row + 1][start_column + 1] == 0:
                self.white_valid_moves.append((1, 1))

            elif self.board[start_row - 1][start_column + 1] == 0:
                self.white_valid_moves.append((-1, 1))

        # For 2
        elif self.board[start_row][start_column] == 2:
            self.red_valid_moves.clear()
            if self.board[start_row - 1][start_column - 1] == 1:
                self.red_valid_moves.append((-2, -2))
                self.board[start_row - 1][start_column - 1] = 0

            elif self.board[start_row + 1][start_column - 1] == 1:
                self.red_valid_moves.append((2, -2))
                self.board[start_row + 1][start_column - 1] = 0

            elif self.board[start_row - 1][start_column - 1] == 0:
                self.red_valid_moves.append((-1, -1))

            elif self.board[start_row + 1][start_column - 1] == 0:
                self.red_valid_moves.append((1, -1))
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? And can you please give us a Minimal Reproductible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: The if statement under the for loop is meant to compare the move which the player picks whether its in the valid_moves by splitting them up in x and y since when we append it its a tuple. The problem is when this if statement is called no movement is allowed on the board. When if we take the if statement away all moves are allowed.

Comment: And this is as small the code I can get since the functions correlate directly

Comment: I want to get to a point when only the moves in the valid moves lists are allowed

Comment: I'll add the more complicated featurea like the King later

Comment: The start and end variables are the positions of the mouse when it's clicked up until it's released a drag mechamism

Comment: I'm curious, if you put a `print` statement under this if: `if np.all(self.board[start_row][start_column] == 1 or 2):`, does it print anything?

Comment: What should I attempt to print

Comment: That bit is fine it's the if statement under the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1 - No movement**

In your code, you never get a motion out of line 8 because your `x` is an integer, and will never equal an array. This code here: `self.board[start_row] - self.board[end_row]` fetches two rows from the board, the row that the mouse started on, and the row that the mouse ended on. Because both of these rows are numpy arrays, when subtracting them, it results in a single-line numpy array. Example:

```py
>>> h = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6],
                  [7, 8, 9]])
>>> h
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> h[0] - h[1] # Subtracting row one of h by row two of h
array([-3, -3, -3])
```

You can see here that subtraction of two numpy arrays always results in another array. Your `x` value is an integer, either `1` or `-1`. An integer will never equal an array that is more than one digit long, and therefore, will always return `False`, meaning your if statement will never run.

To fix this, you simply do not need to reference the board at all. The board's purpose is to tell you if there is a checker or not in each section of the array. You have already created your checker move validation system, this if statement only needs to know if you have moved to a valid spot.
replace this:

```py
if np.all(x == self.board[start_row] - self.board[end_row]) and ...
```

with this:

```py
if x == (start_row - end_row) and ...
```

after all, all you're doing is checking to make sure the distance they have moved horizontally puts them in a valid spot. Do the same to the second part of the if statement.

**Part two - Reversed columns and rows**

In your `if` statement, you are comparing the x value to the rows. x value is across, and uses columns as representation. Not a big deal if you reverse these, but it's very annoying, as it can mess up your entire code, and it is purely a logic error, so your interpreter won't catch it. Simply change your current `if`:

```py
if x == (start_row - end_row) and y == (start_column-end_column):
```

to this, reversing the x's and y's:

```py
if x == (start_column - end_column) and y == (start_row-end_row):
```

**Part 3 - Syntax**

There an error in your code that I don't believe you noticed, and that is this line here:

```py
if np.all(self.board[start_row][start_column] == 1 or 2):
```

With the line above, python breaks this: `self.board[start_row][start_column] == 1 or 2` down differently than you would expect. First, it detects if the board tile in question is equal to 1 (which I assume is black), and then it detects 2, separately. In other words, your `or` is choosing between (True/False) or (2). This: `self.board[start_row][start_column] == 1` will return the True or False, and this: `2` will return the two. Both of these, however will run:

```py
>>> True or 2
True
>>> if True:
    print('Hello World')
    
Hello World
>>> False or 2
2
>>> if 2:
    print('Hello World')
    
Hello World
```

As you can see, the `if` statement will *always* run, resulting in it constantly checking for possible values, meaning that a player could click anywhere, and as long as they move their mouse diagonally, they could create a checker anywhere on the board. To fix this, you need to either duplicate the first part of code, or check if the value is *in a list* of acceptable values. Method one requires more code, and more typing than method two:

```py
if (self.board[start_row][start_column] == 1) or (self.board[start_row][start_column] == 2):
```

which is why I recommend method number two, especially as it is much easier to change a list than 42 characters of `if` statement:

```py
if (self.board[start_row][start_column]) in (1 , 2):
```

To summarize:

```py
    def get_mouse_pos_and_place(self, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, number):
        end_column = end_x // SQUARESIZE
        end_row = end_y // SQUARESIZE
        start_column = start_x // SQUARESIZE
        start_row = start_y // SQUARESIZE
        if (self.board[start_row][start_column]) in (1 , 2)::
            for x, y in self.red_valid_moves:
                if (x == start_column - end_column) and (y == start_row - end_row):
                    self.board[start_row][start_column] = 0
                    self.board[end_row][end_column] = number

    def get_valid_moves(self, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y):
        end_column = end_x // SQUARESIZE
        end_row = end_y // SQUARESIZE
        start_column = start_x // SQUARESIZE
        start_row = start_y // SQUARESIZE
        if self.board[start_row + 1][start_column + 1] == 0:
            self.red_valid_moves.append((1, 1))

        elif self.board[start_row - 1][start_column + 1] == 0:
            self.red_valid_moves.append((-1, 1))
```

Comment: Can u please put it into code so that I can see and understand it better

Comment: Okay. I hope this helps. Try and understand the changes, though, and don't just copy+paste and be done with it

Comment: I have understood what was causing the problem sorry for not accepting the answer

Comment: But could I please post a bit more code about another issue

Comment: The problem with this is normally a couple of moves on some of the moves which should be allowed are not allowed

Comment: Everything is fine but when I have to skip over and delete pieces some moves which should be allowed are not particularly in the 2 and 7 row

Comment: If u see this could you please tak a look at the now edited code since stack overflow isn't letting me post a question and deeming it as similar

Comment: I noticed you added `print` statements for debugging, to tell you what  the valid moves are. When you do a move that doesn't work, is that move in `valid_moves`, but the second function deosn't allow you to make it, or is it not in `valid_moves`?